# ARM to C calling convention, NEON registers to save

Tags: arm, neon, abi

There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/arm-to-c-calling-convention-registers-to-save) that covers regular registers. What about NEON registers. As far as I remember either top half or bottom half of registers have to be preserved across function calls.
I can't find that info anywhere, can somebody clarify that?

thanks

From [the AAPCS, §5.1.1 Core registers](http://www.scribd.com/josephyen/d/6546078-ARM-Architecture-Procedure-Call-Standard#page=15):

- **r0-r3** are the argument and scratch registers; **r0-r1** are also the result registers
- **r4-r8** are callee-save registers
- **r9** might be a callee-save register or not (on some variants of AAPCS it is a special register)
- **r10-r11** are callee-save registers
- **r12-r15** are special registers

From [the AAPCS, §5.1.2.1 VFP register usage conventions (VFP v2, v3 and the Advanced SIMD Extension)](http://www.scribd.com/josephyen/d/6546078-ARM-Architecture-Procedure-Call-Standard#page=17):

- **s16–s31 (d8–d15, q4–q7)** must be preserved
- **s0–s15 (d0–d7, q0–q3)** and **d16–d31 (q8–q15)** do not need to be preserved

Comment: What about FPSCR and FPEXC?

Comment: I'm not even sure about these. For example `5.1.2.1 VFP register usage conventions (VFP v2, v3 and the Advanced SIMD Extension)` covers `FPSCR`, but it's not clear if you should do anything to preserve it or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the AAPCS, §5.1.2.1](http://www.scribd.com/josephyen/d/6546078-ARM-Architecture-Procedure-Call-Standard#page=17):

- **s16–s31 (d8–d15, q4–q7)** must be preserved
- **s0–s15 (d0–d7, q0–q3)** and **d16–d31 (q8–q15)** do not need to be preserved