# Why this code run into infinite loop in ARM

Tags: linux, assembly, arm

I am learning ARM assembly and compiled a code which simply ran a loop 5 times but  when ran it goes to infinite loop

```
.global main
main:
push {ip.lr}
sub r1,r1,r1
well:
ldr r0,=message
bl printf
add r1,r1,#1
cmp r1,#6
bne well
pop {ip,pc}
message:
       .ascii "Amit Singh Tomar\n"
```

Why this code runs in to infinite Loop?

Comment: There is a point in learning curves where you should study more before asking questions.

Comment: @auselen: +1 - StackOverflow should not be a substitute for mental exertion.

Comment: Ok @auselen but I tried different things before asking and kind of got frustrated.So put my question here.I will take care of your comments.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar Be sure that it is not an insult. Sometimes to learn more you need to push yourself. It is a great skill to learn without asking, it helps professionally as well.

Comment: Ok @auselen ,I do take your suggestion and work on it.

Comment: For instance, [heyrick's assembler intro](http://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/apcsintro.html) and other ARM assembler tutorials would be good reading.  Use [google ARM assembler tutorial](https://www.google.ca/#q=arm+assembler+tutorial) to find many good links.

Comment: again possible duplicate of [ARM to C calling convention, registers to save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/arm-to-c-calling-convention-registers-to-save)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` call destroys your `r1`. Save your loop invariant in non-scratch register.

Answer (score 4):

R1 gets trashed by the call to printf - use a non-volatile register instead or save/restore R1 around the call to printf.

Comment: Thanks Paul R ,replacing r1 to r5 worked.I guess printf call will destroy (r0-r4).

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar r0-r3, r4 is not included.