# Parameter passing convention for Function call from ARM Assembly to C

Tags: c, assembly, arm, parameter-passing

I have a C code that calls a function defined in ARM Assembly. Two Parameters have to be passed.

If the function call looks like this:

```
functionName(a, b)
```

the registers `x0` and `x1` hold these values in which order? Is it `x0` holds `a` and `x1` holds `b` or the other way round?

Comment: X0 = a, X1 = b (or in 32-bit R0 = a, R1 = b)

Comment: is there any documentation that explains this?

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0055b/IHI0055B_aapcs64.pdf

Comment: thank you. Where does it talk about the left-right or right-left convention?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ARM to C calling convention, registers to save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/arm-to-c-calling-convention-registers-to-save)

Comment: This is one of the most frequent questions on this tag with many answers including. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261419/arm-to-c-calling-convention-registers-to-save

Answer (score 5):

It took longer to ask the question than to just try it.

```
extern void bar ( unsigned int, unsigned int );

void foo ( void )
{
    bar(5,7);
}
```

compile then disassemble

traditional arm

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
   4:   e3a01007    mov r1, #7
   8:   eafffffe    b   0 <bar>
```

aarch64

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   528000e1    mov w1, #0x7                    // #7
   4:   528000a0    mov w0, #0x5                    // #5
   8:   14000000    b   0 <bar>
   c:   d503201f    nop
```

msp430

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   3e 40 07 00     mov #7, r14 ;#0x0007
   4:   3f 40 05 00     mov #5, r15 ;#0x0005
   8:   b0 12 00 00     call    #0x0000 
   c:   30 41           ret
```

pdp-11

```
00000000 <_foo>:
   0:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
   2:   1185            mov sp, r5
   4:   15e6 0007       mov $7, -(sp)
   8:   15e6 0005       mov $5, -(sp)
   c:   09f7 fff0       jsr pc, 0 <_foo>
  10:   65c6 0004       add $4, sp
  14:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  16:   0087            rts pc
```

Comment: Question looks like arm64? Nothing wrong with your answer though.

Comment: doesnt matter what processor, arm, aarch64, mips, x86, pdp-11.  if you have a compiler for it and want to know the calling convention for two simple parameters.  shouldnt take but around 40 to 50 seconds to find out.

Comment: For future readers: https://godbolt.org/ has ARM, AArch64, MSP430, MIPS, and various other gcc and clang versions (including x86-64), and MSVC.

Comment: No. The specifications of calling conventions are described in the ABI for that platform. Writing a C program to have a look how it works can be a good way to check your understanding AFTER you read the ABI spec, or to complement it. There could be many cases where a simple test simply does not show them. Also, this website has a bigger function to be able to provide knowledge for future users, not just spoon feed the OP. Yours is not a bad answer, but why give an attitude...

Comment: @PeterCordes OK but any compiler can be configured to change the ABI even on the command line. Just because the default settings on godbolt show a specific way to pass a couple of parameters, it does not mean that in real life the calling convention will be exactly the same

Comment: @AlessioSangalli: If you're reverse-engineering, then it really is this simple to figure out which arg goes in which register; unless as you say you're dealing with ABI-changing args like x86 GCC's `-mregparm=3`.  If you're writing your own functions in asm, then yeah you should read the ABI spec to see what other requirements exist like call preserved vs. call clobbered regs, stack alignment, some sequence of operations in the prologue that stack unwinding might depend on, etc.